# Any two points inside a circle are within a diameter of each other.

Tags: inequality, circles, normed-spaces, pigeonhole-principle

In many problems involving the Pigeonhole Principle, we often assume the following lemma:

> **Lemma:** The distance between any two points in a circle of radius $r$ is at most $2r$.

Intuitively, this is obvious: "just stretch out the two points as far as possible until they're diametrically opposite from each other". I was wondering how we could rigorously prove this lemma. I think I can handle proving the $1$-dimensional version as follows:

---

> **Easier Lemma:** If $x,y \in [-r,r]$, then $|y - x| \leq 2r$.

**Proof of Easier Lemma:** Without loss of generality, assume that $-r \leq x \leq y \leq r$. Then it suffices to show that $y - x \leq 2r$. Now recall that since $x \geq -r$, we know that $-x \leq r$. But then since $y \leq r$, we can add the previous two inequalities together to obtain $y - x \leq 2r$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

---

When I try to generalize my proof to two dimensions, I run into a snag in the first line, where I try to drop the absolute value with a "without loss of generality". How can I get around this in the $2$-dimensional version?

Comment: Triangle inequality, $\lVert x-y\rVert \leqslant \lVert x-c\rVert + \lVert c-y\rVert$, where $c$ is the centre.

Comment: Here is another way to do it:

Take two random points $X,Y$.

First extend the line between the two points until it reaches the circle making a chord $AB$ - the chord is at least as long as the segment $XY$ which forms a part of it.

Let $AC$ be the diameter through $A$ - then $ABC$ is a right-angled triangle with $AC$ as hypotenuse.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yes! Your proof makes the other proofs look silly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Fischer's comment, this lemma is actually really trivial to prove. Let's generalize!

Given any metric space $(M, d)$, we define the closed ball of radius $r > 0$ centred at $c \in M$ to be:
$$
B_r[c] = \{x \in M \mid d(x, c) \leq r\}
$$

Using this new notation, we now want prove the following lemma:

> **Generalized Lemma:** If $x,y \in B_r[c]$, then $d(x, y) \leq 2r$.

**Proof of Generalized Lemma:** Given any $x,y \in B_r[c]$, observe that:
\begin{align*}
d(x,y)
&\leq d(x,c) + d(c,y) &\text{by the triangle inequality} \\
&= d(x,c) + d(y,c) &\text{by symmetry} \\
&\leq r + r &\text{since } x,y \in B_r[c] \\
&= 2r
\end{align*}
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

---

Thus, my original lemma can be proved by taking $M = \mathbb R^2$ and defining $d\colon M \times M \to \mathbb R$ by:
$$
d(\vec x, \vec y) = \|\vec x - \vec y \|_2 = \sqrt{(x_1 - y_1)^2 + (x_2 - y_2)^2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the circle is centered at $(0,0)$
$$x_1^2+y_1^2\leq r^2$$
$$x_2^2+y_2^2\leq r^2$$

$$(x_1-x_2)^2+(y_1-y_2)^2 \leq x_1^2+x_2^2+y_1^2+y_2^2+2|x_1x_2+y_1y_2|$$
$$=x_1^2+x_2^2+y_1^2+y_2^2+2|(x_1,y_1)\cdot(x_2,y_2)|\leq 2r^2+2||(x_1,y_1)||||x_2,y_2||=4r^2$$